# Running a python application from source file without using pip install

Tags: python

There is an application where I downloaded the source code and would like to modify it. 
https://github.com/ownaginatious/fbchat-archive-parser
Is there a way to run this program by entered a command such as "python3 main.py" rather than installing the program. When the program is installed, I would simply run the command fbcap.

Comment: If you don't want to pollute your system-wide python, use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project has a `setup.py` file. The "standard" way to run such a thing is to install it (preferably inside a virtualenv) and then run it. Virtualenvs are cheap and lightweight so it's easy to do.

1. First, create a virtualenv. This might be slightly different depending on your platform. I presume you're using Python 3 so [these instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) should work for you. Let's assume you created it in `/tmp/venv1`
2. Activate it using `. /tmp/venv1/bin/activate` (don't forget the initial .). This also might be different if you're on Windows.
3. Now install your program using `python setup.py install`.
4. Run it using `fbcap`.

This will allow you to run the program in a clean fresh python environment and when you're done experimenting, you can simply delete the virtualenv directory.

Comment: My goal is to run this application through a website. Do you have any suggestions on how I could do that. I want to have a user input something and then have the script output something back to the user. Thanks

Comment: You can run it using the `subprocess` module. The command would be something like `/tmp/venv1/bin/python /tmp/venv1/bin/fbcap <rest of the args>`.